# How to get the names of installed video codecs in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, video, avfoundation, codec, qtkit

I am looking for a way to list the names of all installed video codecs with ObjectiveC on OS X Mountain Lion. 
There is a property of `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` called `availableVideoCodecTypes` which returns an array containing to items: `avc1 and 'jpeg`.

My questions are

- how can i get the names of the codec, For example H264 instead of avc1?
- are there only two video codecs installed on my system?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot tell which development platform you are talking about.

Comment: I want to do that on OS X Mountain Lion